# Open refine bat file not loading the full page

Tags: java, performance, openrefine

I am trying to run open refine bat file but it is not loading full page only open refine logo is showing. I took the source code from git hub and imported it in eclipse. But after running code, it is not loading full page. Please suggest anything

I tried all the possible steps which are given in open refine tutorial link. But not able to get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `refine.bat build`? I suspect Eclipse will not build the frontend on its own, and that is needed to fetch the dependencies of libraries.